# Linear discrimant analysis: Proof MLE covariance matrix is biased

Tags: discriminant-analysis

I know that the MLE of the covariance matrix for LDA is:
$$\Sigma_{MLE}=\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{\substack{i=1}{g_i=k}}^N(x_i-\hat{\mu}_{k})(x_i-\hat{\mu}_{k})^T.$$
How can I proof that this is a biased estimator, i.e. $E[\hat{\Sigma}_{MLE}]\neq\Sigma$? I am confused by the subscripts of the summations. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by considering the case $K=N=1,$ where there are no subscripts.

Comment: I understand that perfectly, even K=1, N=n (Multivariate normal distribution), but the problems arise for me when K is not equal to 1.

Comment: That's a good start.  The next step is to write out the sum for $K=2,$ then.  This helps you overcome the notational complications and focus on the underlying idea.  Once you see that, the pattern should become evident.